# Spark multicharacter delimiter write Unprintable characters in data written

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having a process which creates feed to external systems which is having a multi character delimiter. The data itself have some json document as columns. I amusing spark 2.3 , yet to upgrade to higher version

```
                    df=df.select([col(c).cast("string") for c in df.columns])
                    """fill na with emptystring to avoid null created and filed dropped"""
                    df=df.na.fill("")
                    filedelimiter = "|~"
                    headername=filedelimiter.join(df.columns)
                    header = True
                    """concat all columns to handle multidelimiter"""
                    df=df.withColumn(headername, concat_ws(filedelimiter, *df.columns))
                    df.select(df[headername]).write.format("csv").mode('overwrite').option("quoteAll", "false").option("quote","\u0000").option("header", header).save(filepath + "/")
```

When i try code - the output itself get created with a unprintable characters. I did a hdfs get and tried a cat on the file below is the output with ^@ in the front proballing the daya is quoting with null. Also the file is data file

```
$ cat testfile.txt
PLANOGRAM_ID|~FIXTURE_ID|~NAME|~PARTID|~MORE_ATTR
5606|~45345|~DISPLAY BASE|~|~{"REORDER_NUMBER":"asdas","FIXTURE_TYPE":"BEAM","VSG_BAR_CODE":"345435","PMT_PROJECT_ID":"NON-PMT","MERCHANDISING_DEPT":"ROUGH ELECTRICAL","CATEGORY_NAME":"ROUGH ELECTRICAL","UNIQUE_KEY":"34543","FIXTURE_CATEGORY":"RACKING","IMT_CATEGORY":"RACKING AND RACK ACCESSORIES","FIXTURE_DESC":"RACEWAY WIRE MOLD 69ININ DISPLAY SHELF","SAS_FIXTURE_ID":"3453","SEGMENT":0}

$ cat -v testfile.txt
PLANOGRAM_ID|~FIXTURE_ID|~NAME|~PARTID|~MORE_ATTR
^@5606|~45345|~DISPLAY BASE|~|~{"REORDER_NUMBER":"asdas","FIXTURE_TYPE":"BEAM","VSG_BAR_CODE":"345435","PMT_PROJECT_ID":"NON-PMT","MERCHANDISING_DEPT":"ROUGH ELECTRICAL","CATEGORY_NAME":"ROUGH ELECTRICAL","UNIQUE_KEY":"34543","FIXTURE_CATEGORY":"RACKING","IMT_CATEGORY":"RACKING AND RACK ACCESSORIES","FIXTURE_DESC":"RACEWAY WIRE MOLD 69ININ DISPLAY SHELF","SAS_FIXTURE_ID":"3453","SEGMENT":0}^@
```

$ file testfile.txt
testfile.txt: data

When I tried changing the command nothing provided the right out expected.

```
df.limit(10).select(df[headername]).write.format("csv").mode('overwrite').option("escapeQuotes" ,"False").option("header", header).save(filepath + "/")
df.limit(10).select(df[headername]).write.format("csv").mode('overwrite').option("escapeQuotes" ,"False").option("escape" ,"").option("quote","" ).option("header", header).save(filepath + "/")
df.limit(10).select(df[headername]).write.format("csv").mode('overwrite').option("escapeQuotes" ,"False").option("escape" ,"").option("header", header).save(filepath + "/")
```

This provided the results with quotes in the front or all quotes are escaped with

```
$ cat testfile.txt
PLANOGRAM_ID|~FIXTURE_ID|~NAME|~PARTID|~MORE_ATTR
"5606|~45345|~asdasda BASE|~|~{\"REORDER_NUMBER\":\"asa\",\"FIXTURE_TYPE\":\"BEAM\",\"VSG_BAR_CODE\":\"assa\",\"PMT_PROJECT_ID\":\"NON-PMT\",\"MERCHANDISING_DEPT\":\"ROUGH ELECTRICAL\",\"CATEGORY_NAME\":\"ROUGH ELECTRICAL\",\"UNIQUE_KEY\":\"asa\",\"FIXTURE_CATEGORY\":\"RACKING\",\"IMT_CATEGORY\":\"RACKING AND RACK ACCESSORIES\",\"FIXTURE_DESC\":\"DISPLAY SHELF\",\"SAS_FIXTURE_ID\":\"BS 60\",\"SEGMENT\":0}"

$ cat testfile.txt
PLANOGRAM_ID|~FIXTURE_ID|~NAME|~PARTID|~MORE_ATTR
"5606|~45345|~DISPLAY BASE|~|~{"REORDER_NUMBER":"asdas","FIXTURE_TYPE":"BEAM","VSG_BAR_CODE":"345435","PMT_PROJECT_ID":"NON-PMT","MERCHANDISING_DEPT":"ROUGH ELECTRICAL","CATEGORY_NAME":"ROUGH ELECTRICAL","UNIQUE_KEY":"34543","FIXTURE_CATEGORY":"RACKING","IMT_CATEGORY":"RACKING AND RACK ACCESSORIES","FIXTURE_DESC":"RACEWAY WIRE MOLD 69ININ DISPLAY SHELF","SAS_FIXTURE_ID":"3453","SEGMENT":0}"
```

Expected results is to have the file with just the data and not having anything appended or escaped.

```
$ cat -v testfile.txt
PLANOGRAM_ID|~FIXTURE_ID|~NAME|~PARTID|~MORE_ATTR
5606|~45345|~DISPLAY BASE|~|~{"REORDER_NUMBER":"asdas","FIXTURE_TYPE":"BEAM","VSG_BAR_CODE":"345435","PMT_PROJECT_ID":"NON-PMT","MERCHANDISING_DEPT":"ROUGH ELECTRICAL","CATEGORY_NAME":"ROUGH ELECTRICAL","UNIQUE_KEY":"34543","FIXTURE_CATEGORY":"RACKING","IMT_CATEGORY":"RACKING AND RACK ACCESSORIES","FIXTURE_DESC":"RACEWAY WIRE MOLD 69ININ DISPLAY SHELF","SAS_FIXTURE_ID":"3453","SEGMENT":0}

$ file testfile.txt
testfile.txt: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

I will not be able to apply sed or other unix commands as the NAS response is pretty poor in such huge files. I wanted to do the operation is Spark itself and just place back on the local.
Please let me know if this is possible to achieve in Pyspark.

Comment: It's hard to debug and test without the actual file, however my suggestion is load it as text file and replace unprintable characters with this `.withColumn('value', F.regexp_replace('value', '^\x01', '')) # try to find UTF-8 code of your unprintable character here`

Comment: The data doesn't have any unprintable characters, spark is creating those characters at start and end.. you can read a dumyy file with data as 1|2|{"feild" : "1","feild2" : "3"} with | as delimited and write back with |~ as delimiter. Same issue will occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't save it as CSV if you don't actually use CSV's features, or its features would drive you nuts. Instead, you can save as a plain text file with the header prepended into original dataframe.

```py
header_as_a_row = spark.createDataFrame([(headername,)], ['anynamedoesntmatter']) # "produce" header record
(header_as_a_row
    .union(df.select(df[headername])) # "prepend" it into original dataframe
    .write
    .format('text') # use text instead of csv
    .mode('overwrite')
    .save(filepath + "/")
)
```

Comment: I will wait to accepting the answer , but this doesn't guarantee the header will be on order and on each part file. That's the reason I had to use the csv mode. In my case may be without header workaround might be sufficient, but looks like there no way to write text with header and csv without its features

Comment: Well, yes that's correct. If the header is fixed, you can handle it on reading phase